# Android SDK Bundle fails to download says "Unknown Network Error"

Tags: android, sdk, download

Every time I tried to download the Android SDK Bundle, it gets fully downloaded (480MB/480MB) then it'll saying the download failed due to "Unknown Network Error".
I've tried the download several times with the same results, any insight as to how I fix this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as per the rules outlined in [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Use different browser.. like safari. Issue is observed with chrome and FF.

Comment: idiots at facebook didnt know that ? They have to check this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Suffered the problem with my chrome, solved it using my **Internet Explorer**.

I feel dirty. And Google should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. I got the same error all the time I tried, and I was stuck with it. Then I finally solved it using BitComet.

I suggest you to download this through BitComet.

I opened this link, "https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk#download", accepted the Terms and Conditions, and then right clicked on "**Download the SDK ADT Bundle for Windows**" and then clicked on "**Download With BitComet**"

And It Works.....

Answer (score 0):

I have just used suggestion by RStar.

Downloaded using BitComet.

Package unzips and works just fine.

OT completed. 
Result: Success

I had attempted download of ADT Bundle for Windows several times using Chrome's download manager. Observed DL would reach 490 of 510 MB and begin to stall, finally failing in the last few bytes with Unknown Network Error.

Note: The tags on this question are appropriate, as they helped me to find a solution to *my* problem as searched for.

That is all.